# Is there a reason this Picasso line is not loading my images?

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am building a simple blog feature and using picasso to load images into recyclerview in android studio but the images don't load, Please can someone help me understand why. See the related code section below:

public class BlogRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Context context;
    private List blogList;

```
// Constructor
public BlogRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Blog> blogList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.blogList = blogList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view, context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Now bind the views and the data
    Blog blog = blogList.get(position);
    String imageUrl = null;

    holder.title.setText(blog.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(blog.getDesc());

    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(blog.getTimeStamp())).getTime());

    holder.timeStamp.setText(formattedDate);

    imageUrl = blog.getImage();

    //TODO: Use Picasso library to load image
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return blogList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView desc;
    public TextView timeStamp;
    public ImageView image;
    String userId;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view, Context ctx) {
        super(view);

        context = ctx;

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postTitleList);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postTextList);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.postImageList);
        timeStamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeStampList);

        userId = null;

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // We can go to the next activity
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try Glide instead of Picasso , for me Picasso didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @WowoOt do have any links to a quick guide to using Glide?

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: It is very similar to Picasso

Comment: thanks @WowoOt I would check it out but i really would like to know why Picasso isn't working this time. i used it previously and it worked but why not on this project?

Comment: same happened with me , Good Luck.